# Map view problems

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mkmapview

struct SchoolsMap: View {

```
@EnvironmentObject private var newMap : SchoolModel

var share = SchoolModel().schools

@State private var latitudinal = 0.0
@State private var longitude = 0.0

let pin = MKPointAnnotation()

@State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D( latitude: 40.503851973654783, longitude: -74.450847996722231), span: MKCoordinateSpan (latitudeDelta: 0.9, longitudeDelta: 0.9))


var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        ZStack{
            
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: share){ location in
                
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.503851973654, longitude: -74.45084799672)) {
                    VStack{
                        NavigationLink{
                            SchoolsDetailView(data: location)
                        } label: {
                            Text(location.properties.name!)
                                .bold()
                            Circle()
                                .stroke(.red)
                                .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                        }
                       
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

}

My map view doesn't show up with the annotations. The region updates whenever I change it, but the map doesn't show any of my annotations. Anyone know why?

Comment: Because you have hardcoded the coordinates instead of using the coordinates from the location

Comment: I've tried  location.geometry.coordinates.last!, longitude: location.geometry.coordinates.first!) and it didn't work. The values are double

Comment: Your issue is likely in that code somewhere that is an unorthodox looking model location should have a coordinates variable in it directly.

Comment: You already have a `SchoolModel` in `newMap`, no need for another one in `share`.
So try removing `var share = SchoolModel().schools` and use `newMap.schools` instead, with the 
`MapAnnotation(coordinate: location...) ` where you use your `location` coordinates from your `schools`.
  Since you don't show what `schools` and their `location` are, we can only guess.